# How would I perform this task in O(1) (amortized)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I just wanted to confirm with somebody that I'm on the right track before I proceed. The problem states that when I want to add a new element to an already FULL array, I must "expand the array in O(1)(amortized)".

Is this saying that every time I insert a new element into a full list that I should add 5 elements or something like that so I don't have to perform an expansion every time a new element is added?

Comment: Yes, this is the basic idea.  Assuming expanding the array is just a constant penalty, it would be `O(1)`.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You mean no, right? The basic idea is to increase the size by an amount proportional to the current size, not to increase it by a constant number of elements, like the OP proposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this saying that every time I insert a new element into a full list that I should add 5 elements or something like that so I don't have to perform an expansion every time a new element is added?

Sort of. But any *constant* number of extra slots will have the same problem: even if you only have to copy to a new array every five insertions, that still averages out to O(*n*) time per insertion, because O(<sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>5</sub>) = O(*n*).

Instead, you need to add a number of slots that's proportional to the current size of the array. The simplest approach is to double the array size whenever you need to grow, which averages out to O(<sup>*n*</sup>/<sub>*n*</sub>) = O(1); but increasing it by (say) 50%, or any other constant proportion, would have the same effect.

Comment: Note that doubling leads to a travelling vector problem.  Suppose you start with 1k used for your array.  You then allocate 2k, copy, and return the first 1k to the heap.  Next, you allocate 4k, then return 2k.  There is now 3k free, and 4k used.  Next cycle 7k free, 8k used.  The free storage never gets big enough to be recycled for a new allocation, so total memory for the process is 2x what you are actually using!  If you use 1.5, after a few cycles the stuff you freed is big enough to fit the next allocation.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it may depend on your compiler/OS, but the standard for this is to:

```
1. Allocate a new buffer with size 50 percent larger than the current buffer size
2. Copy the data from the current buffer to the new buffer.
3. Perhaps fiddle with addresses so the new buffer replaces the old buffer.
```

So this takes O(1)

Comment: Your step #2 is O(N).

Comment: @selbie -- yes, that **part** of the algorithm is O(n), but it's not done every time; it's done for every nth insertion (loosely speaking), which is why the **overall** complexity of appending is O(1) amortized. This is the approach that `std::vector` uses, for example.

Comment: Oh, I see... Thanks!